# how to control robot movements from a webapp on any device without a keyboard?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to map buttons on my app screen to teleop but I can't figure out how.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343601/how-to-control-robot-movements-from-a-webapp-on-any-device-without-a-keyboard?/) by [VinayMaida](https://answers.ros.org/users/51388/vinaymaida/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-02-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) on 2020-02-08**:
Is desktop application an alternative ?, you might consider have look to rqt

**Comment by [VinayMaida](https://answers.ros.org/users/51388/vinaymaida/) on 2020-02-08**:
its a web app... i have made the entire front end its a must to use web app

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are probably better off sending the twist message yourself directly using something like [robotwebtools](http://robotwebtools.org/)

Please don’t post basically the same question twice, it will split up answers, and wastes time.

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2020-02-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2020-02-08**:
Getting a web app to send keypresses  to a terminal window is not related to ros, if you want to do it that way stackoverflow would probably be a more appropriate place to get help

**Comment by [VinayMaida](https://answers.ros.org/users/51388/vinaymaida/) on 2020-02-13**:
robotwebtools helped thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[teleop_twist_web](https://github.com/tue-robotics/teleop_twist_web) might be a package of interest.

It sends out a [Twist](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html) message based on touch movements on the screen.
Useful for single-thumb operating your robot from a mobile device.

---

Originally posted by [Timple86](https://answers.ros.org/users/22432/timple86/) with karma: 80 on 2020-02-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1